# Compiling C Programs On z/OS Via The Shell In Unix System Services (USS)

Tags: c, shell, unix, mainframe, zos

I have a C file residing in the USS filesystem.  My C file is pretty basic. It contains logic to print "Hello World". I execute: *c89 [filename]*

I get a return code (`rc`) of `CCN0634(U)`. The same rc is thrown if I try the cc compiler. I Google the aforementioned `rc`. The IBM Knowledge Center tells me the following:

`Check that the compiler is installed correctly. Make sure there is enough memory in the region to fetch the module. You may need to specify the runtime option HEAP(,,,FREE,,) to prevent the compiler from running out of memory.`

The above explanation didn't make much sense. I Googled for some solutions. All of the search results led to compilation in batch using JCL. It was overwhelming as there were many different flavors.

**Q1:** What’s the simplest way to compile a C program on the Unix Shell Services?

**Q2:** How do I check if a compiler is installed? cc --version doesn’t work.

#### Expected Result

- Compilation of my C program

#### Actual Result

- My C program doesn't compile.

Comment: You are having difficulty compiling a program we can't see on an unspecified machine with an unknown OS version and you'd like some help? Please add your code and the missing details - thank you.

Comment: It also appears that the XL C/C++ compiler either is not installed properly at your site, or your RACF OMVS permissions and/or login shell script has invalid information. You should contact your systems programmer.

Comment: You say "cc --version doesn't work". Do you get an error message when you type that command? What if you replace `cc` by `xlc`? A quick Google search indicates that `xlc -qversion` or `xlc -qversion=verbose` should work -- if `xlc` is installed.

Comment: A module is mentioned in the message.  Can you provide the entire message including the module that could not be loaded?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, I do get a err: `-- is not a valid option`. Yes, it is installed: `z/OS V2.3 XL C/C++`.

Comment: @Hogstrom: Entire message is `Unable to load CCNEP. Compilation terminated.`

Comment: @KaziR What about `xlc -qversion`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: The output of `xlc -qversion` is >> `z/OS V2.3 XL C/C++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am running on z/OS 2.4.

One common issue is that the libraries that host the compiler are not accessible.  I have this setting in my shell environment:

`export STEPLIB="none:CEE.SCEERUN:CBC.SCLBDLL:CBC.ACCNCMP"`  The last dataset hosts the module you indicate is not found.

In addition, these here are some additional settings (Note: some of these libraries may be different on your system due to customization but these are the default libraries):

```
declare -x _C89_CLIB_PREFIX="CBC"
declare -x _C89_INCDIRS="/usr/include /usr/lpp/ioclib/include"
declare -x _C89_LIBDIRS="/lib /usr/lib"
declare -x _C89_PLIB_PREFIX="CEE"
declare -x _C89_SLIB_PREFIX="SYS1"
declare -x _C89_WORK_UNIT="SYSDA"
declare -x _CC_CLIB_PREFIX="CBC"
declare -x _CC_INCDIRS="/usr/include /usr/lpp/ioclib/include"
declare -x _CC_LIBDIRS="/lib /usr/lib"
declare -x _CC_PLIB_PREFIX="CEE"
declare -x _CC_SLIB_PREFIX="SYS1"
declare -x _CC_WORK_UNIT="SYSDA"
declare -x _CEE_RUNOPTS="FILETAG(AUTOCVT,AUTOTAG) POSIX(ON)"
declare -x _CXX_CLIB_PREFIX="CBC"
declare -x _CXX_INCDIRS="/usr/include /usr/lpp/ioclib/include"
declare -x _CXX_LIBDIRS="/lib /usr/lib"
declare -x _CXX_PLIB_PREFIX="CEE"
declare -x _CXX_SLIB_PREFIX="SYS1"
declare -x _CXX_WORK_UNIT="SYSDA"
```

**In answer to Q1** here is the simplest way:

Below is the output from my shell session in USS:

```
IBMUSER:/u/ibmuser #>cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return(0);
}
IBMUSER:/u/ibmuser #>cc t.c
IBMUSER:/u/ibmuser #>./a.out
hello world
```

Comment: Your answer to Q1 is correct. I was able to SSH in & use `cc` to compile my C program. I believe this worked because it utilized my Mac's CC bin.

Comment: No, if you're logged into the z/OS machine, `cc` will not invoke `cc` or `CC` on your Macintosh.

Comment: Valid point. Then the critical Q is: Why does cc work when I SSH in but not when I TSO in?

Comment: @KaziR: I don't know what TSO is, but check your `$PATH`. When you ssh in, what does `type cc` say? And `ls -l $(type -p cc)` ? `cc` may or may not be a symbolic link to `xlc`. `cc` may be in a directory that's in your `$PATH` when you SSH in, but not when you TSO in.

Comment: Note that the ```declare``` command is  a ```bash``` built-in and is not part of the standard shells shipped with z/OS.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to compile a C program in USS on z/OS is by using the xlc utility. Here is an example with two command line options -v and -qphaseid that show the information about the version of the utility and the compiler components that were involved in the compile process:

```
xlc -v -c -qphaseid a.c
FSUM0000I  Utility(xlc)                      Level(D170323.1712)
exec: export(export,XL_CONFIG=/bin/../usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/etc/xlc.cfg:xlc,NULL)
exec: /usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/exe/ccndrvr(/usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/exe/ccndrvr,./,./a.c,*.c,CMDOPTS(DEFINE(errno=(*__errno())),NOTEST,-qoe,-qargparse,-qexecops,-qflag=i,-qhalt=16,-qnodebug,-qnolsearch,-qredir,-qlocale=POSIX,-qlongname,-qmaxmem=*,-qmemory,-qnestinc=255,-qnoexpmac,-qnoexportall,-qnogonumber,-qtarget=le,-qnolibansi,-qlist=/dev/fd1,-qnolist,-qnomargins,-qnooffset,-qnosequence,-qnoshowinc,-qsource=/dev/fd1,-qnosource,-qnoxref,-qterminal,-qnooptimize,-qplist=host,-qspill=128,-qstart,-qnoipa,DEFINE(_OPEN_DEFAULT=1),-qansialias,-qcpluscmt,-qlanglvl=extended,-qnoupconv,-qnoalias,-qnoaggregate,-qnoinfo,-qnoevents,-qrent,-qinline=auto:noreport:100:1000,-qnoinline),object(./a.o),-qphaseid,NOPPONLY,NULL)
exec: export(export,STEPLIB=CBC.SCCNCMP:CEE.SCEERUN2:CEE.SCEERUN,NULL)
exec: export(export,_C89_ACCEPTABLE_RC=4,NULL)
CCN0000(I) Product(5650-ZOS) Phase(CCNEOPTP) Level(D190612.Z2R3)
CCN0000(I) Product(5650-ZOS) Phase(CCNDRVR ) Level(D190612.Z2R3)
CCN0000(I) Product(5650-ZOS) Phase(CCNEP   ) Level(D190612.Z2R3)
CCN0000(I) Product(5650-ZOS) Phase(CCNETBY ) Level(D190612.Z2R3)
CCN0000(I) Product(5650-ZOS) Phase(CCNECWI ) Level(D190612.Z2R3)
```

The XL C/C++ compiler is a priced feature on z/OS so your system may not have it installed. A properly installed compiler will have a valid configuration file in **/bin/../usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/etc/xlc.cfg**

Perhaps a clarification is in order as it may not be obvious that there are two utilities in USS that invoke the XL C/C++ compiler.

1. The c89 utility whose operation is controlled by a number of environment variables (most users would run into difficulties figuring out how to define the required environment variables)
2. The xlc utility whose operation is controlled by a configuration file which is easier to setup. Most users will be fine with the default configuration file customized by a system programmer who installed the compiler, but if a more sophisticated user needs a different setup the configuration file can be copied into a private file and modified to satisfy the need. Once modified it can be used by including -F /path_to_modified_config_file option on the command line.